# error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `string' to `UnityEngine.UI.Text'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just decided to try Unity. And i have problem. Can someone expain me whats wrong? :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Game : MonoBehaviour
{
public Text summ;
public Buttons shopbtn = new Buttons;

void Start()
{
    shopbtn.btntext="Example";
    Debug.Log(shopbtn.btntext);
}}
_________________________________________________
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Buttons : MonoBehaviour 
{
public Text btntext;
}
```

Just one simple example. Why it does not work?

> error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type string to `UnityEngine.UI.Text'

But when btntext is situated in Game class it works.

Comment: You probably need `shopbtn.btntext.text = "Example"`.  Make sure that `text` is all lower case.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the text property of the `Text` instance:

```
shopbtn.btntext.text="Example";
```

Currently you have a field of type `Text` and you are trying to assign a `string` to it, hence the error.

Comment: I thought that since it was already in type Text, there is no longer a reason to add the ```.text``` at the end.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try improved

```
shopbtn.btntext.Text = (UnityEngine.UI.Text)"Example";
```